# Is it possible to dock the Lync contact list as a taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, lync

The question is in the title.  I don't see anything in Options, and dragging to the edges just gives me normal Windows edge-maximize behavior.

I'm using Windows 7 x64 if it makes a difference.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to dock the Lync IM client (contact list) to the right or left side of your desktop, similar to how other popular IM clients work, so that when an application is maximized it expands only to the edge of the Lync IM client but not over or under it?

Comment: Lync can be docked with Outlook 2010.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/ocsclients/thread/24b03d1c-d829-4c4a-8dfd-3995f8c3827a

Comment: You're correct - I'd like to dock it like some of the other IM clients I've used.  Your tip is actually a good enough answer for my purposes that I'll accept it.

Comment: "[...] similar to how other popular IM clients work" -- I like how this is 2013 and basic IM client features are completely missing, which includes not only docking but also tabbed chat windows (which is possible, but requires a separate, stand-alone application)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lync can be docked with Outlook 2010.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/ocsclients/thread/24b03d1c-d829-4c4a-8dfd-3995f8c3827a